# Something deleted user data from MySite

Tags: 2010, my-site

One of our users received this warning:

> The My Site of [USER] is scheduled for deletion in 14 days. As their manager you are now the temporary owner of their site. This temporary ownership gives you access to the site to copy any business-related information you might need. To access the site use this URL: `https://mysites/personal/[USER]`

And unfortunately, I didn't take it seriously, just checked his account, because we never activated this function before and was disabled in this time. 14 days later, user data was deleted and here is my question: Why?

- User is active for years and works with his MySite documents quite often
- User profile in AD has not been deleted, changed or migrated to other domain
- Import and every night user profile synchronization works without errors
- Automatic deletion was never activated, as well as warning e-mails
- MySite cleanup job is not running
- No change was made in MySite app. during last two months or so

Can I find somehow which other pages are scheduled for deletion? Can I remove them somehow? And can I disable this function once and for all? Next time, it could be almost everyone if something pick active profiles too. Thank you for any clue.

Comment: I have same question (or problem)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this post can be helpful - [blog link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/seanearp/archive/2009/03/04/sharepoint-profile-cleanup.aspx) although it's about SP 2007.

**Here's the citation:**

Update to the paragraph above… commenter Chris reminded me that I was not quite right about the My Site deletion.  While the e-mail itself is not related to the “Site Use confirmation and deletion” feature, sites are not actually deleted unless that feature is turned on.  The e-mail to the manager is telling a fib.  If the “Site Use confirmation and deletion” feature is enabled, the site is deleted due to the fact that the user never confirms the e-mail checking to see if they are still using the site; not due to the My Site Cleanup Job itself.  I also came across another great resource on My Sites and disabled/deleted users from Phil Wicklund that is well worth reading: [link](http://philwicklund.com/whitepapers/Documents/My%20Site%20Concerning%20Scenarios%20Study%20and%20Strategy.pdf)

Comment: Thank you Alex, regarding the whitepaper, restoring is not an option, new MySite page was automaticaly created after next logon, even user ID don't bother me, but it is empty, data are lost (and cannot be found in user reycle bin neither second-stage bin). I have the opposite problem that paper says, I don't want to mark and delete anything. There is no profiles missing from Import, MySite cleanup job is disabled, Automatic site deletion feature is disabled and data was deleted anyway.